# How Would You Categorize A Cap or Spread On A Monthly Sum Option?

Tags: monthly, spread

I'm just trying to determine the appropriate naming convention for a category that holds cap or spread, or in other words, what category can I put cap and spread (in this context) into?  Are they "Features" of a monthly sum option, or "Limits" ... I really don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When speaking with quants, I call such things *Boundary Conditions*.  With traders I tend to use *Terms* or *Features*.

Comment: I like "Features"